# F# type providers - how to assign a value to an Out parameter?

Tags: f#, type-providers

The constructor for `ProvidedParameter` accepts a value `isOut:bool`, which I take to mean that provided functions can support C# `out` parameters.

However, I can't find any way to construct an Expr to set the *value* of the `out` parameter in the `InvokeCode`. Here's an example:

```
testType.AddMember(
    let outParam = ProvidedParameter("outDate", typeof<DateTime>, true)
    let outFunc = ProvidedMethod("GetTomorrow", [outParam], typeof<unit>)
    do outFunc.InvokeCode <-
        fun p ->
            // "Invalid expression on left of assignment"
            <@@ do %%(p.[1]) <- DateTime.Today.AddDays 1.0 @@>
    outFunc)
```

I also wasn't able to do it using the static functions in the `Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Expr` type. I can't figure out how to get from `p.[1]`, which is an `Expr`, to a `Var`, which appears to be required for every sort of let/set expression.

Comment: I had a quick look and, even with no code, the provided method does not look like a method with an `out` parameter, so my guess is that this is not supported. I'd first try to update to the latest version of the type provider SDK, but even then, I'm not sure if there's a way to do this - that said, I'd probably use normal return value instead anyway!